# How to export/import a typedef in flutter

Tags: flutter

With flowtype or typescript you can just import types where you need them.

If I make a typedef in flutter but need it in several files how can I do this?

As an example:

```
typedef VoidNoteOnClick = void Function(int index);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `import 'path/to/typedef.dart';`